# Microsoft Identity Web invalid token in Blazor WASM

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor, microsoft-identity-platform

I am just finished trying to implement this: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/1.%20Desktop%20app%20calls%20Web%20API

Instead of using a WPF application I am using a Blazor WASM client.

I added the token to the outgoing requests to my .net core API but I always get a 401.

Blazor authenticates well and gets the token back, seems to be working fine but:

- the audience has the wrong GUID
- "scp" (scope) is missing, hence the token being invalid for usage

If I run the sample from the link mentioned above and decode the token I can see a correct AUD & SCP in the token. So it's probably something with my configuration in Blazor?

**Config in Blazor**

```
// AD authentication
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("api://xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/access_as_user");
});

builder.Services
       .AddHttpClient<IApiClient, ApiClient>(client => client.BaseAddress = _baseUri)
       .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

**Response**

```
Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience '63ee4227-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' is invalid"
```

The audience GUID is the clientID of my Blazor app registration

**Code in Startup.cs**

```
...
services.AddProtectedWebApi(Configuration)
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
...

...
app.UseAuthentication(); 
app.UseAuthorization();
...
```

Any idea what could have been wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When I was learning to use Blazor WebAssembly I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which does something very similar and it may be easier for you to implement as you don't have to try and convert any codefrom WPF.

However, one thing to try is to change this:

```
options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("api://xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/access_as_user");
```

To this:

```
options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/access_as_user");
```

In my application I am calling two API endpoints, one is hosted within the same domain as the Blazor application and the other is on a separate domain. When requesting a token for the external domain the *api://* prefix must be used. However, for the same domain it must be excluded.